# Как компоновать (собирать) сложные объекты?

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Вэб для меня новое, по этому если я где-то буду говорить неправильно или непонятно, то прошу поправить или переспросить. Задача такая - построить один объект из много частей.
То есть, есть рисунки фона, текстовых полей, кнопок, которые получают значения из файлов на сервере и в дальнейшем они будут анимированы. Но я ни как не разберусь, как правильно все это скомпоновать в отдельный объект, который можно было бы либо создавать как класс либо ещё что-то делать... Вот как есть компонент кнопка, у неё есть свойства label, которому можно задавать значение. Вот как так же создать свой объект? Если можно расскажите последовательность действий?

**И я так понял, что в html нельзя создать собственные элементы, по этому вопрос - какой элемент нужно создать, чтобы объединить другие элементы?**

```
<img class="rect_1" src="img/rect.jpg" height="337" width="344">
```

**Дополнение:**

[image]

Постараюсь объяснить подробнее - вот если бы я делал в объектно ориентированных языках и мне нужно было бы создать уникальный объект ( как у меня на картинке в самом верху ),
то я бы создал класс UniqueObject и в нем бы создавал другие классы ( на картинке зеленым это отдельный уникальный компонент, а серым показывается из чего он состоит ).
Так же в классе UniqueObject я бы сделал методы для позиционирования других уникальных классов и так по всей иерархии. И вот если бы перед инитом приложения я узнал, что у пользователя маленький монитор, то создал бы только один экземпляр этого уникального класса, а если большой, то создал бы столько, сколько смогло бы поместится на экране.
Вот как такое же сделать в html+другие языки? Если перейти к конкретной задачи, то у меня есть картинка-фон, по верх неё должны быть ещё несколько одинаковых картинок с текстовым полем поверх них и несколько кнопок. И в зависимости от размера экрана я должен выводить или один такой скомпанованый компонент или два. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Честно говоря, мало что из прочитанного понятно :) В разметке html есть тэги, атрибуты, значения атрибутов и грубо говоря элементы. Например:

  1. img - тэг
  2. <img> - элемент
  3. <img class="rect_1"> - атрибут class со значением rect_1 у элемента img

Может, попробуете переформулировать свой вопрос исходя из этих пояснений?

    <img class="rect_1" src="img/rect.jpg" height="337" width="344">

Здесь вы создали элемент "изображение" и задали ей атрибуты класса (для применения CSS свойств), ресурса (путь до изображения), высоты, длинны

Comment: > Вот как такое же сделать в html+другие языки?

html+javascript

> И в зависимости от размера экрана я должен выводить или один такой скомпанованый компонент или два. Как такое сделать?

Тут или javascript или очень крутой css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как дополнение ответа [[@likerRr](/users/5625/likerrr)](/users/5625/likerrr).

В html есть теги. При помощи тегов создаются элементы (то, что вы неверно называете объектами). У элементов есть атрибуты (не свойства). В javascript есть объекты, а у этих объектов есть свойства и методы. Вы можете получать доступ, создавать, редактировать, удалять элементы посредством javascript. Когда вы работаете с [dom деревом](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom), с помощью javascript, вы работаете с объектами (javascript объектами). Вообщем, почитайте про dom дерево, и все немного прояснится.

Comment: @alvoro: Спасибо Вам! У меня ещё много вопросов - 1) в html можно создавать собственные элементы? Для примера, есть элемент button, а вот можно создать sampleButton? 2) как менять координаты объекта? Вот я взял и картинку присвои свойству - var object = document.images; а как её сдвинуть, не доходит.

Comment: @shatal Просто написать <mytag></mytag> нельзя. Валидатор ругается. Но, вроде, их можно создавать используя [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/). Менять координаты объекта надо используя свойство style объекта, который ссылается на ваш элемент. Благодаря ему вы можете менять css стили вашего элемента. [Тут](http://jsfiddle.net/wJqBn/) элементарный примерчик.

Comment: @alvoro: фенкс! Немного разобрался, но от js я немного другого ждал, почему-то был уверен, что в нем есть классы... И ещё вопрос - что лучше angularjs или angularjs?

Comment: > что лучше angularjs или angularjs?

Однозначно angularjs))) Но никто не заставляет вас его использовать. Для создания "своих" элементов вы можете просто орудовать div-ами с разными классами или создать функцию в javascript, который будет возвращать ваш набор элементов ([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sApD4/)). Классы есть, но не такие, какими вы привыкли их видеть. Разберетесь с протототипным наследованием и успех будет неизбежным.

Comment: >>> И ещё вопрос - что лучше angularjs или angularjs?

В чём альтернатива - то?

Comment: ахахахахаха!!!!!!! Только сейчас заметил что написал... Что лучше - angularjs или Backbone.js?

Comment: @shatal тут небольшое сравнение js фреймворков на примере простой задачи. http://todomvc.com/ выбирайте по вкусу "что лучше" это холивар, мне например Ember не подошел, стар я для него, не могу столько памяти на синтаксис выкинуть. а angular подошел, backbone хардкорным показался для современного мира.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам просто ознакомиться с технологией создания страниц на HTML (язык разметки гипертекста). Вот список курсов и учебников, некоторые на русском, но в основном на английском

- (русский) http://ru.html.net/tutorials/html/
- (интерактивный, самые-самые азы) http://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-one-o-one/0/1
- (ещё один, но уже с технологией CSS для разукрашивания страниц) http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss
- http://html.net/
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp
- http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/gettingstarted/
- (русский, самый полный справочник по HTML и CSS) http://htmlbook.ru

Эти знания позволят создавать статические, неизменные страницы. Чтобы менять в них что-нибудь, потребуется либо серверный язык программирования (PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl, ASP.Net и ещё огромное количество вариантов), либо клиентский (vbscript, javascript, CoffeeScript). Учебники по этим языкам можно поискать через поисковые системы. Есть большое количество интерактивных курсов по Javascript.

И ещё вариант - если речь идёт не о HTML и javascript. Это могут быть Flash, Flex, Silverlight и другие языки, создающие программы, встраивающиеся в страницу HTML, в них картинки и тексты не имеют мало общего с HTML, но знать HTML всё равно придётся. Учебники по этим языкам можно поискать через поисковые системы.